# How can I make my code repeat an action? I used "for i in range(x):" but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: python

```
import random
import statistics
import math

numbers = [508, 507, 600, 600, 610, 610, 590, 601, 600, 600, 600, 610, 610, 610, 600, 600, 600, 620, 620, 620, 610, 620,
           620, 620, 620, 620, 630, 610, 630, 630, 620, 630, 630, 620, 600, 610, 620, 620, 600, 590, 600, 600, 630, 580,
           580, 570, 580, 590, 560, 580, 580, 570, 580, 580, 580, 580, 580, 570, 580, 580, 560, 570, 560, 580, 570, 580,
           560, 580, 540, 560, 550, 550, 580, 550, 550, 550, 560, 540, 570, 580, 580, 570, 570, 560, 550, 570, 540, 550,
           560]
numbers2 = [5.08, 5.07, 6, 6, 6.1, 6.1, 5.9, 6.01, 6, 6, 6, 6.1, 6.1, 6.1, 6, 6, 6, 6.2, 6.2, 6.2, 6.1, 6.2, 6.2, 6.2,
            6.2, 6.2, 6.3, 6.1, 6.3, 6.3, 6.2, 6.3, 6.3, 6.2, 6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.2, 6, 5.9, 6, 6, 6.3, 5.8, 5.8, 5.7, 5.8,
            5.9, 5.6, 5.8, 5.8, 5.7, 5.8, 5.8, 5.8, 5.8, 5.8, 5.7, 5.8, 5.8, 5.6, 5.7, 5.6, 5.8, 5.7, 5.8, 5.6, 5.8,
            5.4, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 5.8, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.6, 5.4, 5.7, 5.8, 5.8, 5.7, 5.7, 5.6, 5.5, 5.7, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6]
for i in range(100):
    mu = statistics.mean(numbers2)
    c = 0
    sd = []
    for i in range(len(numbers2)):
        b = (numbers2[c] - mu) ** 2
        sd.append(b)
        c += 1
    s2 = sum(sd)
    s = math.sqrt(s2)

    sample = []
    for i in range(20):
        sample.append(random.choice(numbers))
    mus = sum(sample)
    mus = mus / 100
    mus = mus / 20

    t = (mus - mu) / (s / math.sqrt(len(numbers)))
    tvalues = []
    tvalues.append(t)

print(tvalues)
meantv = sum(tvalues) / len(tvalues)
print(meantv)
```

---

What am I missing? The first `for i in range(100):` I used seems to not repeat the code...
is there a missing indent I missed, or can I just not repeat so many things at once?
(or could I have somehow missed out on specifying what exactly to repeat?)

Comment: You should create the `tvalues` list **before** the loop. Then you will actually collect more than one element ;)

Comment: In every iteration of your loop range(100) you set tvalues to be empty list `tvalues = []` then append to it. so at the end of each loop iteration you will have only one value in tvalues, on the next loop you will remove that entry and assign a new empty list for tvalues and append to it. so after the 100 loops, tvalues will only have one entry which will be the entry from the last loop

Comment: oooh I didn't realize thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Try moving `tvalues = []` outside of the loop. This way you are setting that variable to an empty list every time you run the loop.